# Pandas dataframe replace column value based on group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with the below structure,

```
   master_mac    slave_mac        uuid           rawData               
0  ac233fc01403  ac233f26492b     e2c56db5       NaN                                                         
1  ac233fc01403  ac233f26492b     e2c56db5       NaN                                                         
2  ac233fc01403  ac233f26492b     e2c56db5       NaN                                                          
3  ac233fc01403  ac233f26492b     e2c56db5       ac0228  
4  ac233fc01403  e464eecba5eb     NaN            590080             
5  ac233fc01403  ac233f26492b     e2c56db5       ac0228  
6  ac233fc01403  ac233f26492b     e2c56db5       NaN                                                          
7  ac233fc01403  ac233f26492b     e2c56db5       636800
```

- If an "uuid" column is not empty for a group i.e., "master_mac" & "slave_mac", then the respective rows should contain NaN for "rawData" column.

The resultant outcome needs to be,

```
 master_mac    slave_mac        uuid           rawData               
0  ac233fc01403  ac233f26492b     e2c56db5       NaN                                                         
1  ac233fc01403  ac233f26492b     e2c56db5       NaN                                                         
2  ac233fc01403  ac233f26492b     e2c56db5       NaN                                                          
3  ac233fc01403  ac233f26492b     e2c56db5       NaN  
4  ac233fc01403  e464eecba5eb     NaN            590080             
5  ac233fc01403  ac233f26492b     e2c56db5       NaN  
6  ac233fc01403  ac233f26492b     e2c56db5       NaN                                                          
7  ac233fc01403  ac233f26492b     e2c56db5       NaN
```

Can anyone help me out in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
m = df['uuid'].notna()
```

If need processes per groups use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) for test at least one non `NaN` per groups:

```
m = df['uuid'].notna().groupby([df['master_mac'],df['slave_mac']]).transform('any')

df['rawData'] = df['rawData'].mask(m)
print (df)
     master_mac     slave_mac      uuid rawData
0  ac233fc01403  ac233f26492b  e2c56db5     NaN
1  ac233fc01403  ac233f26492b  e2c56db5     NaN
2  ac233fc01403  ac233f26492b  e2c56db5     NaN
3  ac233fc01403  ac233f26492b  e2c56db5     NaN
4  ac233fc01403  e464eecba5eb       NaN  590080
5  ac233fc01403  ac233f26492b  e2c56db5     NaN
6  ac233fc01403  ac233f26492b  e2c56db5     NaN
7  ac233fc01403  ac233f26492b  e2c56db5     NaN
```

Or:

```
df.loc[m, 'rawData'] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to modify for each row the value in column `rawData` based on the value in column `uuid`, you could simply do this:

```
df['rawData'].loc[df['uuid'].notna()] = np.nan
```